# dynamic path in Keystone file using keystone-storage-adapter-s3

Tags: keystonejs

How do you generate a path based on dynamic data inside the model the file is being saved to?  An example would be having a `User` model with a `fileAttachment` field.  If one instance of the `User` model has a `registrationNumber` of `123`, I want to store their file at */123/fileName.pdf*.  If another user has a `registrationNumber` of `456`, I want to store their file at *456/fileName.pdf*.  The `path` field accepts a string, and unfortunately during the time it is set, there's no access to the model fields.  In addition, the file is named and uploaded to AWS by the time the `pre('save', ...)` hook is executed which prevents renaming there.

Comment: You could always just upload to AWS with aws-sdk in the post('save") hook.

Comment: thanks @QuinnKeaveney, I was hoping to use the built in S3 field type, but that's not looking possible.  I'm either going to follow your suggestion in the post('save') hook, or flatten the structure on the AWS server.